# Mail gets delivered to spam folder when delivering through external SMTP server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-spam

I'm currently using PHPMailer to send emails within PHP, like such:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "MY_EXTERNAL_SMTP_SERVER";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "info@xxxxxx.com";
$mail->Password = "MY_PASSWORD";
$mail->From = "info@xxxxxx.com";
$mail->FromName = "xxxxxx.com";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode("test")."?=";
$mail->Body = "123";
$mail->Send()
```

When I send emails to Gmail, I've found that sending the email from a Yahoo! SMTP server sends to the inbox, but sending the email from any other external SMTP server results in the message being marked as spam automatically.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: It may help to put a real looking name in the FromName and if there is a way to put a real name with the AddAddress. And what are you you doing with the subject line? That might what is flagging it.

Comment: Questions about emails being delivered as spam are [generally considered off topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam). It might help to look at the various postmaster guidelines or check resources for whatever SMTP service you're using.

Comment: It's not the FromName that's important but the FromAddress - if its domain is not a match for the server you're sending from, it will probably be classified as spam because it will fail SPF/DMARC checks. You've also based your code on an obsolete example. Why are you futzing with UTF-8 encoding in the subject? PHPMailer does all that for you.

Comment: I Change FromName, But Re Send To Spam.

Comment: When Use Swiftmailer Library, Doesen't Send To Spam.